# Should I be using unnest_wider and rowMeans to get the average of a list column?

Tags: r, unnest

I have a simple data set. The row names are a meaningful index and column 1 has a list of values. What I eventually want is the average of that list for each row name.

What it looks like now:

| row name | years |
| --- | --- |
| 108457 | [1200, 1200, 1540, 1890] |
| 237021 | [1600, 1270, 1270] |

What I eventually want it to look like:

| row name | years |
| --- | --- |
| 108457 | mean of list |
| 237021 | mean of list |

Currently, I'm trying to use `unnest_wider(years)`. My plan is to then afterwards use `rowMeans()` to find the mean of the unnested row. I can then merge the row name and average value with my main data set, so I'm not too concerned with deleting the new columns.

However, this whole process is taking a while and I'm having some issues with `unnest_wider`. Currently, when I try:

```
unnest_wider(dataset, colname)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in `as_indices_impl()`:
> ! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
> ✖ Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame<years:list>`.
> ℹ It must be numeric or character.

When I try:

`unnest_wider(colname)`

My computer just runs endlessly and it looks like it's counting... it doesn't stop and I have to quit the application to terminate processing.

I had previously tried to directly apply `rowMeans`, use `mean(df$ColName)`, and use `apply(ColName, mean)`.

I wonder if there's a more efficient way?

It may be that I shouldn't have created the list in the first place. It looks like it does now because I converted it from this format:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 108457 | 1200 |
| 108457 | 1200 |
| 108457 | 1540 |
| 237021 | 1600 |
| 108457 | 1890 |
| 237021 | 1270 |

I converted it using `pivot_wide`r and then `as.data.frame.(t(dataset))`

Should I have tried to get the averages directly from this format? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Can you provide your sample data using `dput()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original data look like they do in the latter table, you could simply find the mean by group based on `ColumnA`:

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "ColumnA    ColumnB
108457  1200
108457  1200
108457  1540
237021  1600
108457  1890
237021  1270", header = TRUE)
```

Base R

```
aggregate(df$ColumnB, list(df$ColumnA), FUN=mean) 

# Group.1      x
# 1  108457 1457.5
# 2  237021 1435.0
```

Dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ColumnA) %>%
  summarise(mean_years = mean(ColumnB))

#  ColumnA mean_years
#    <int>      <dbl>
#1  108457      1458.
#2  237021      1435
```

Answer (score 2):

For your vectors in each row, you can use `sapply` to iterate over each row to calculate the mean, then just return the mean for each row name.

```
df$years <- sapply(df$years, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
        years
108457 1457.5
237021 1380.0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(years = structure(list(c(1200, 1200, 1540, 1890
), c(1600, 1270, 1270)), class = "AsIs")), row.names = c("108457", 
"237021"), class = "data.frame")
```

Or we can use `data.table` to get the mean, if your data look like the latter, long format dataset.

```
library(data.table)

as.data.table(df2)[, list(ColumnB = mean(ColumnB)), by = ColumnA]
```

*Output*

```
   ColumnA ColumnB
1:  108457  1457.5
2:  237021  1435.0
```

*Data*

```
df2 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(108457L, 108457L, 108457L, 237021L, 
108457L, 237021L), ColumnB = c(1200L, 1200L, 1540L, 1600L, 1890L, 
1270L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```